# How can I play Crysis 2 without shutting down ProcExp and Visual Studio?

Tags: drm, crysis-2

I'm a developer. When I have some spare time, I like to play the occasional game. Crysis 2 won't run if I have Visual Studio or Process Explorer running – which I do at all times. Sometimes I have a debugging session running; I can't just close VS without losing a lot of state.

What (legal) options are available to stop this madness?

Comment: I would recommend not combining your development machine with your gaming machine as much as possible. This is not unique to Crysis 2.

Comment: out of curiousity, what actually happens when you try to run Cry2 with VS open?

Comment: @warsong I was told "A required security module cannot be activated" and the game wouldn't start. But see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading to Crysis 2 v1.9 and installing the DX11 tessellation patch has enabled me to play regardless of what else I have running. I'm not sure which of these two installs did it, but I suspect it was the v1.9 upgrade.

Comment: @kotekzot thanks for the reminder; when I first posted it, I wasn't allowed to mark it accepted, presumably to prevent some sort of abuse...

Answer (score 7):

This site cannot give you legal advice. However, it *may* be legal in your jurisdiction to download a DRM-free copy of the game (e.g. via BitTorrent) since you already own the game. It may *still* be legal even if the EULA claims that you can’t do it (many sections in EULAs do not have force of law in many jurisdictions). You will have to research the legality of this option within your jurisdiction yourself.

Comment: Timwi please don't delete your answer and repost it because you were downvoted. You can edit your answer to help correct issues, editing your post allows people to change their vote if they choose.

Comment: If anyone has an issue with this answer, please use our [meta] site, or our [chat], to voice it and to discuss it further.

Comment: @Resorath: Unfortunately people don’t actually change their votes.